# How can I add boolean column to Vuetify table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have header in Vuetify , but when I add value which is boolean.The table doesn't show me this column.
This is my header: headers: [{ text: 'isActive', value: "isActive"}]

Answer (score 1):

I found how can we achieve it, we must use slot.

```
after <v-data-table> tag


   <template v-slot:item.yourBoolean="{ item }">
       {{ item.yourBoolean? 'true' : 'false' }}
   </template>
```